# Missing vtable: should virtual function be redeclared in header file?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, header-files

I am getting error `NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition. "vtable for Algorithm2A"`. I suppose the problem in my base class I declared the function as pure virtual, and then in the header `.h` of derived class I redeclared it, in order to be able to implement it in the implementation file `.cpp`.

**IAlgorithm2.h** -- that is my abstract class

```
#include "IAlgorithm1.h"

//! Algorithm2 interface
class IAlgorithm2 {

public:

    ~IAlgorithm2() {
    }

    virtual std::vector<int> calculateLCP(std::string BWT)=0;
};
```

Now, I have the implementation of this in `Algorithm2.h`, and`Algorithm2.cpp`.

**Algorithm2A.hpp**

```
class Algorithm2A : public IAlgorithm2 {

protected:
    IAlgorithm1 &algorithm1;

    std::vector<Interval> getIntervals(int i, int j) {
        return algorithm1.getIntervals(i, j);
    }

public:
    Algorithm2A(IAlgorithm1 &a) : algorithm1(a) {
    }

    std::vector<int> calculateLCP(std::string BWT);
};
```

**Algorithm2A.cpp**

```
#include "Algorithm2A.hpp"


std::vector<int> Algorithm2A::calculateLCP(std::string BWT) {
    // implementation of this
}
```

How should this be done? If I remove the definition from the `Algorithm2A.h` that it won't compile, and if I leave it there, than there is a vtable problem.

**edit**: this is not a matter of templates

**IAlgorithm1.h**

```
//! Algorithm1 interface
class IAlgorithm1 {

protected:
    virtual std::string uniqueCharsInInterval(int i, int j)=0;


public:

    ~IAlgorithm1() {
    }

    virtual std::vector<Interval> getIntervals(int i, int j)=0;
};

#endif /* Algorithm1_h */
```

**Algorithm1A.h**

```
#include "IAlgorithm1.h"

class Algorithm1A : public IAlgorithm1 {

protected:
    IRank &rank;
    OrderedAlphabet &alphabet;
    std::map<symbol_type, occurence_type> &C;
    std::string &BWT;

public:
        Algorithm1A(IRank &r,
                   OrderedAlphabet &a,
                   std::map<symbol_type, occurence_type> &c,
                   std::string &bwt):
                   rank(r), alphabet(a), C(c), BWT(bwt) {
        }

std::string uniqueCharsInInterval(int i, int j);
```

There is also an implementation file `Algorithm1A.cpp`

Comment: You do need to repeat the function declaration in `Algorithm2A`. What is the vtable problem? Any error messages? Note that the header file is called `Algorithm2A.h`, but you `#include <Algorithm2A.hpp>`. Note the `pp` at the end.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Algorithm2A::~Algorithm2A()", referenced from:
      _main in main-ccca0a.o
  "vtable for Algorithm1A", referenced from:
      _main in main-ccca0a.o, and there is a NOTE. I will edit, and give also Algorithm1A code.

Comment: How are you building it? Looks like you haven't linked everything.

Comment: How should I be building it? I have several more files, and they include each others, so I think everything is linked.

Comment: You have declared the deconstructor  ~Algorithm2A(); but you haven't implemented it. Maybe `virtual ~Algorithm2A() {};` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Having attempted to solve this, there seem to be myriad other problems. Please post a **[testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** as instructed in the site rules.

Comment: `Algorithm1A` is hardly useful because it depends on other undisclosed parts of the code. Please build an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition

The error message tells you what is wrong! The first non-inline virtual member function in `IAlgorithm2` is not defined!

Since your first such function at present is `calculateLCP`, and you don't actually *want* to define it, the common fix is to give `IAlgorithm2` a virtual destructor (which you should be doing anyway), with an empty definition.

You will also need to provide a definition for the `Algorithm2A::~Algorithm2A` that you have declared, or remove that declaration.

Comment: I did as you said and had the following issue: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for Algorithm1A", referenced from:
      _main in main-b98ecb.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Algorithm2A", referenced from:
      _main in main-b98ecb.o

Comment: @Whizzil: And what's `IAlgorithm1`?

Comment: The you have some other problem somewhere else. This is why you need to post **testcases**, not stripped down code snippets with missing definitions of things. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added IAlgorithm1 files aswell.

Comment: @Whizzil: Stop! Click on the link I gave you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No matter how bad you treat me, I will still keep upvoting your answers. _ _....

Comment: @Des1gnWizard: When have I "treated you bad"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh may I say I thought you were serious with the last comment ...LOL... I thought I have told you Ima student but you still hurt me so much...Oh...My glass heart..T.T....